# How to render SweetAlert React

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert

I'm trying to use SweetAlert as an alert when the user clicks the logout button. This is how I'm doing it. The SweetAlert (example copied from their repo):

```
const signOutUser = () => {
return (
    <SweetAlert
        warning
        showCancel
        confirmBtnText="Yes, delete it!"
        confirmBtnBsStyle="danger"
        title="Are you sure?"
        onConfirm={() => console.log('hey')}
        onCancel={() => console.log('bye')}
        focusCancelBtn
    >
        You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!
    </SweetAlert>
)}
```

And this is how I'm trying to call it:

```
const Border = () => (
    ...
    <a onClick={signOutUser}/>
    ...
)
```

The problem is that when I click it nothing happens. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `SweetAlert` component needs to always be rendered (except specific cases). What triggers the SweetAlert is the `show` prop, which is a **Boolean**.

You can bind the `show` prop to a state of your component. Let me show you an example:

```
export default function YourAlert() {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <SweetAlert
      warning
      showCancel
      show={isOpen} //Notice how we bind the show property to our component state
      confirmBtnText="Yes, delete it!"
      confirmBtnBsStyle="danger"
      title="Are you sure?"
      onConfirm={() => console.log("hey")}
      onCancel={() => {
        console.log("bye");
        setOpen(false); // Don't forget to close the modal
      }}
      focusCancelBtn
    >
      You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!
    </SweetAlert>

    <Button
        onClick={()=>{
            setOpen(true); // Open the modal
        }}
    >Open the alert</Button>
  );
}
```

Pay attention to where I commented, as it will make you understand the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/chentsulin/sweetalert-react) SweetAlert component has a show prop

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import SweetAlert from 'sweetalert-react';

    // ...

    render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({ show: true })}>Alert</button>
      <SweetAlert
        show={this.state.show}
        title="Demo"
        text="SweetAlert in React"
        onConfirm={() => this.setState({ show: false })}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

so you need to pass a boolean value to that prop and toggle it

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a component into an onclick like that.

Read this docs page about [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

You can get the button to update a state variable, and then conditionally render the alert component dependant upon the value of that state variable.

Here's an example (using a red div, but sub that in for a SweetAlert):

```js
const SignOutUser = () => (
  <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
    You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!
  </div>
);


const App = () => {

  const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = React.useState(true)
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
    
      <button onClick={() => setShowAlert(false)}>Click Me</button>
      
      {!showAlert && <SignOutUser/>}
      
    </div>
  );
}



ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```